# What's the advantage of using the Asp.Net Core Identity system for user accounts over just hashing passwords myself?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm creating a web application using Asp.Net Core MVC. It will only be dealing with a small amount of users when it goes live. This is my first time using Asp.Net and I was wondering if I need to use the Identity system for managing user accounts and logins, or if I can simply create my own login page and hash and store the passwords myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your Login mechanism but make sure to follow security best practices.

Asp.net Identity package will do it for you by default like making sure you encrypt your password good crypto and have salt and access control through claims which you can extend.

But I would suggest to go with Identity. It would create below tables for you.

[image: Asp.net Identity]

And manage all of this hassle for you.
[image]

You can take hint from above tables and field and create what you require. All the best.